# i get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). using pandas

Tags: pandas

i get error while running this code
what to do?
i get error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
unrealized = [0, 0.50, 0.90, 0.20, 3, 6, 7, 2]
    def stoploss():
        df = pd.DataFrame({"price": unrealized})
        df['high'] = df.cummax()
        if df['high'] <= 0.10:
            df['trailingstop'] = -0.50
            df['signalstop'] = df['price'] < df['trailingstop']
        if df['high'] >= 0.10:
            df['trailingstop'] = df['high'] - 0.10
            df['signalstop'] = df['price'] < df['trailingstop']
        return df['signalstop'].iloc[-1]
    
    print(stoploss())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is because the truth value of a series is ambiguous. But what does that mean? Just check the output of `df['high']<=0.1` and you'll see a series of True/False values depending on if the condition is met or not. And you are asking the truth value of this series by using the `if` statement. And what should that be? That is exactly what the error is telling you. "Should I use any or all or what should I do with this series?"

But I assume you want to do something else: You want to set these two extra columns depending on the value in the `high` column. Use the `.loc` with a condition to set a value for all items matching the condition as described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

So the code might look like this (if I guessed your intention correctly):

```
df['high'] = df.cummax()
df.loc[df['high']<=0.1,'trailingstop'] = -0.50
df.loc[df['high']<=0.1,'signalstop'] = df['price'] < df['trailingstop']
df.loc[df['high']>=0.1,'trailingstop'] = df['high']-0.10
df.loc[df['high']>=0.1,'signalstop'] = df['price'] < df['trailingstop']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the lines

```
if df['high'] <= 0.10:
```

and

```
if df['high'] >= 0.10:
```

Because you are comparing a whole series against a number

Not entirely sure what your goal is, but here is some working code:

```
unrealized = [0, 0.50, 0.90, 0.20, 3, 6, 7, 2]
def stoploss():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"price": unrealized})
    df['high'] = df.cummax()

    df['trailingstop'] = 0 # just to create the series in the DF
    df['trailingstop'][df['high'] <= 0.10] = -0.50
    df['trailingstop'][df['high'] >= 0.10] = df['high'] - 0.10
    print(df['trailingstop'])
    
    df['signalstop'] = df['price'] < df['trailingstop']
    print(df['signalstop'])
    
    return df['signalstop'].iloc[-1]

print(stoploss())
```

Result:

```
0   -0.5
1    0.4
2    0.8
3    0.8
4    2.9
5    5.9
6    6.9
7    6.9
Name: trailingstop, dtype: float64
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
Name: signalstop, dtype: bool
True
```